# Java LayoutGrid to display another Class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on a simple GUI that consists of 3 Java Classes:

1 - the buttons
2 - the screen
3 - Displays the Screen and the Buttons side by side.

The concept of the GUI is to somewhat mimic this, but only with the big screen and the buttons:
http://www2.explorando.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/b1183-urna-eletronica-brasileira.jpg

My idea for the 3rd class was to make a GridLayout of 1x2 and somehow display the other two classes on the same Grid. How can I do that?

Not sure if the code is important here, but here it goes, Class Buttons:

```
package apresentacao;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TelaUrna extends JFrame{
  private JButton tecla1;
  private JButton tecla2;
  private JButton tecla3;
  private JButton tecla4;
  private JButton tecla5;
  private JButton tecla6;
  private JButton tecla7;
  private JButton tecla8;
  private JButton tecla9;
  private JButton tecla0;
  private JButton teclaBranco;
  private JButton teclaCorrige;
  private JButton teclaConfirma;
  private JButton teclaVazia;
  private JButton teclaVazia2;

public TelaUrna() {

    //instanciar os componentes!!!
    tecla1 = new JButton();
    tecla2 = new JButton();
    tecla3 = new JButton();
    tecla4 = new JButton();
    tecla5 = new JButton();
    tecla6 = new JButton();
    tecla7 = new JButton();
    tecla8 = new JButton();
    tecla9 = new JButton();
    tecla0 = new JButton();
    teclaBranco = new JButton();
    teclaCorrige = new JButton();
    teclaConfirma = new JButton();
    teclaVazia = new JButton();
    teclaVazia2 = new JButton();

    //configura o container
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));

    //configurar os componentes
    tecla1.setText("1");
    tecla1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla2.setText("2");
    tecla2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla3.setText("3");
    tecla3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla4.setText("4");
    tecla4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla5.setText("5");
    tecla5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla5.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla6.setText("6");
    tecla6.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla6.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla7.setText("7");
    tecla7.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla7.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla8.setText("8");
    tecla8.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla8.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla9.setText("9");
    tecla9.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla9.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    tecla0.setText("0");
    tecla0.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    tecla0.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    teclaBranco.setText("BRANCO");
    teclaBranco.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    teclaCorrige.setText("CORRIGE");
    teclaCorrige.setBackground(Color.RED);
    teclaConfirma.setText("CONFIRMA");
    teclaConfirma.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    teclaVazia.setText("");
    teclaVazia2.setText("");

    //setar acoes

    //adicionar no Container, Pack, VisibleTrue, Centralizar e controle da saida
    container.add(tecla1);
    container.add(tecla2);
    container.add(tecla3);
    container.add(tecla4);
    container.add(tecla5);
    container.add(tecla6);
    container.add(tecla7);
    container.add(tecla8);
    container.add(tecla9);
    container.add(teclaVazia);
    container.add(tecla0);
    container.add(teclaVazia2);
    container.add(teclaBranco);
    container.add(teclaCorrige);
    container.add(teclaConfirma);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //tratar eventos


}
private class GerenciadorBotoes implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    }

}
}
```

Class Screens which right now is just a test screen

```
package apresentacao;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TelaVisual extends JFrame {
    private JLabel teste = new JLabel();

  public TelaVisual() {
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));

    teste.setText("testando");

    container.add(teste);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JPanel Class: [enter link description here](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/uiswing/components/panel.html)

```
public class Urna extends JFrame {
    public Urna() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(<some layout manager that fits your needs>);
        container.add(new TelaVisual());
        container.add(new TelaUrna());

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

public class TelaVisual extends JPanel {
    private JLabel teste = new JLabel();

    public TelaVisual() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));

        teste.setText("testando");

        this.add(teste);
    }
}

public class TelaUrna extends JPanel {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    public TelaUrna() {
        // your code here
        // instead of container.something, use this.something
    }
}
```

keep in mind that JPanel is a Container subclass so you can use it just like you were doing in with the object returned by the getContentPane() meyhod